# The $2$nd law of thermodynamics in a general relativistic context?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity

We all know that the $2$nd Law of the Thermodynamics can be expressed as:

$$ \frac{dS_{universe}}{dt} \geq 0 $$

I asked my professor if I could replace the time derivative with some kind of co-variant derivative. He said he didn't think so. My question is how does one express the $2$nd law of thermodynamics in a general relativistic context?

Comment: $S$ is a scalar, so it shouldn't matter whether or not you use the covariant derivative. That is to say, if $k$ is a vector which points in the $t$-direction in your spacetime, then:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}S = \nabla_k S$$